# Filtering by created_at (start_datetime and end_datetime) picks only one date which is end_datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I am trying to create a filter for my *revenue_controller show action*, but its not working very well.

This is what I have done in the code below, but it picks the *end_datetime* alone when I filter by date.

**revenue_controller.rb**

What am trying to do in the `show` action is default my search to 30days from now, and if params filled with date, use the selected datetime.

```
module Admin
  module Statistic
    class RevenuesController < BaseController

      def show
        @revenues_reports = Currency.all.map do |currency|
          puts params
          start_datetime = if params[:created_at].nil? then
                             30.days.ago
                           else
                             params[:created_at].slice(0..15)
                           end
          end_datetime = if params[:created_at].nil? then
                           Time.now
                         else
                           params[:created_at].slice(0..15)
                         end
          get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
        end
      end

      def get_revenue_report_for_currency(currency, start_datetime, end_datetime)
        puts "start: #{start_datetime}" # I added this to see from the log the start_datetime it picks
        puts "end: #{end_datetime}" # I added this to see from the log the end_datetime it picks
        total_withdraw_fees_charged = Withdraw.where(:currency => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_withdraw_network_fees_charged = 0.3 * total_withdraw_fees_charged
        net_income_from_withdraws = total_withdraw_fees_charged - total_withdraw_network_fees_charged

        total_sell_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderAsk', :bid => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_buy_order_fees_charged = Order.where(:type => 'OrderBid', :ask => currency.id, :created_at => start_datetime..end_datetime).sum(:fee)
        total_trading_fees = total_sell_order_fees_charged + total_buy_order_fees_charged

        total_fees = net_income_from_withdraws + total_trading_fees

        {
          currency: currency.code.upcase,
          total_withdraw_fees_charged: total_withdraw_fees_charged,
          total_withdraw_network_fees_charged: total_withdraw_network_fees_charged,
          net_income_from_withdraws: net_income_from_withdraws,
          total_sell_order_fees_charged: total_sell_order_fees_charged,
          total_buy_order_fees_charged: total_buy_order_fees_charged,
          total_trading_fees: total_trading_fees,
          total_fees: total_fees
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
.panel.panel-primary
  .panel-heading
    h4.panel-title = t('admin.statistic.filter')
  .panel-body
    = form_tag(admin_statistic_revenue_path, :method => 'get', class: 'form-horizontal') do |f|
      .row
        .col.col-xs-3
          label[for="#"]
            | Start Date:
            input.form-control.created_at.date_time_filter.from[name="[created_at]" type="#" value=""]
        .col.col-xs-3
          label[for="#"]
            | End Date:
            input.form-control.created_at.date_time_filter.to[name="[created_at]" type="#" value=""]
        = button_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-info', :name => nil
```

**browser params url**

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/statistic/revenue?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%5Bcreated_at%5D=2018-08-01+00%3A00&%5Bcreated_at%5D=2018-10-05+00%3A00
```

**development_logs**

[image: logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use single parameter name for two different parameters `created_at_from` and `created_at_to`:

```
    .col.col-xs-3
      label[for="#"]
        | Start Date:
        input.form-control.created_at.date_time_filter.from[name="created_at_from" type="#" value=""]
    .col.col-xs-3
      label[for="#"]
        | End Date:
        input.form-control.created_at.date_time_filter.to[name="created_at_to" type="#" value=""]
```

`created_at` is usually `datetime`, so will have non-zero time for most records.
And `2018-10-05 12:34:56 +0100` is greater than `2018-10-05 00:00:00`.

Correct filter for 'records created at specific date' is 'records created after that day has started, but before and of day':

```
start_datetime = if params[:created_at_from].present?
                   Time.zone.parse(params[:created_at_from]).beginning_of_day
                 else
                   30.days.ago
                 end
end_datetime = if params[:created_at_to].present?
                 Time.zone.parse(params[:created_at_to]).end_of_day
               else
                 Time.zone.now
               end
```

Also note `zone`, because depending on timezone day may start in different universal time.

Comment: It works but there is problem. And that is: `{"utf8"=>"✓", "created_at_from"=>"2018-10-01 00:00", "created_at_to"=>"2018-10-05 00:00", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"admin/statistic/revenues"}` `start: 2018-10-01 00:00:00` `end: 2018-10-05 23:59:59` So I removed `end_of_day` and `beginning_of_day` methods because I do not need it.

Comment: Thank you @Vasfed